# Cumulative filters on wordpress rest api with nuxt

Tags: wordpress, rest, filter, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm quite new to vue.js and I'm trying to do something like this: https://appendto.com/2017/05/building-tutorial-search-app-vue/
but with nuxt.js and getting the data from the wordpress rest api.

So far I managed to make a dynamic menu based on a wordpress menu, and dynamic url for pages and custom post type.

I have a page that lists the custom post type (experte) and in that page

I would like to be able to filter those post-type with a text search and by categories.

Problem 1

The text search works fine with the code below. If I type a letter or a word, the list under gets reduced accordingly (I managed to list the posts type through the API). But if I empty the text input the list stays filtered and I don't know why... I resolved this with stocking the return of the axios call to the post types in another variable (orig) which I use in the filterExpertes method but I'm not sure this a good practice...

Problem 2

I managed to build dynamically the checkbox list based on wordpress rest api and using vue dev tools, I can see that my selected variable gets updated when I make a selection. Nonetheless, the list gets empty as soon as a box is checked.

On the wordpress side I arranged that the rest response includes the post type categories like this (code returned if I go to my custom post type endpoint http://lesexpertes.test/wp-json/wp/v2/experte (result of the axios request)

```
[
  {
    "id": 120,
    "date": "2018-03-29T10:02:01",
    "date_gmt": "2018-03-29T08:02:01",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http://lesexpertes.test/experte/aperiam-itaque-enim-omnis/"
    },
    "modified": "2018-03-29T18:03:23",
    "modified_gmt": "2018-03-29T16:03:23",
    "slug": "julia",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "experte",
    "link": "http://lesexpertes.test/experte/julia/",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Julia"
    },
    "content": {
      "rendered": "<h2>Nemo aut fuga ad voluptatem placeat aliquam quia. Voluptatibus nihil dolorem assumenda repellat ipsum excepturi possimus. Dolorem optio blanditiis eius rem distinctio id eveniet</h2>\n<p>Veritatis odit <a title=\"Excepturi consequatur pariatur quisquam voluptas.\" href=\"http://www.quigley.info/natus-et-cupiditate-repudiandae-illum-et\">et quos quaerat. Deserunt qui in</a> pariatur libero atque. Aperiam sint consectetur deserunt necessitatibus. Laboriosam sunt facilis qui beatae. Qui dignissimos quia dolores. Dolores molestiae ullam id. Temporibus ut autem fugiat <a title=\"Possimus.\" href=\"http://williamson.info/\">modi aut sed soluta.</a> eligendi modi corrupti necessitatibus unde libero alias Repudiandae delectus fugiat ea quos dolorum quasi dolorem Porro delectus dolore iure explicabo. Rerum blanditiis <a title=\"Quaerat eos dicta facilis.\" href=\"http://www.heaney.com/soluta-exercitationem-qui-quaerat-et-quo-nostrum.html\">quam consequatur maxime</a> Et rerum aliquam natus sequi sed. Deserunt consequuntur quo quos earum est. Neque officiis explicabo nihil eum. Eaque porro perspiciatis voluptas animi eveniet. sint quibusdam ut Voluptatem dolores quidem consequatur unde. Omnis <a title=\"Distinctio non numquam.\" href=\"http://www.cruickshank.com/vitae-quia-laborum-harum-ipsam-tempore-enim\">dolore quas ipsum ut quasi. Autem</a> <a title=\"Odio quas similique.\" href=\"http://www.johnson.org/ut-aspernatur-eum-recusandae-voluptatem-tempora-rerum\">incidunt vero fuga</a> magnam magnam. Laudantium ratione impedit consequatur. Nemo veniam ipsam reiciendis in. Rerum labore magni dicta saepe doloremque laudantium. Voluptatem eos qui sit aut voluptas eveniet. Numquam et accusamus nisi dolorem. Vel porro vitae sint hic. Ut nam quam aut <a title=\"Consequatur ullam magni aliquam quo error voluptas.\" href=\"http://www.boyle.biz/qui-aut-aperiam-inventore-omnis-accusantium.html\">autem esse eum.</a></p>\n",
      "protected": false
    },
    "author": 1,
    "featured_media": 121,
    "template": "",
    "categories": [
      11,
      10
    ],
    "langue": [

    ],
    "better_featured_image": {
      "id": 121,
      "alt_text": "",
      "caption": "",
      "description": "",
      "media_type": "image",
      "media_details": {
        "width": 300,
        "height": 300,
        "file": "2018/03/e9c4f864-3555-3e8c-b0f7-73f9d4d74348.jpg",
        "sizes": {
          "thumbnail": {
            "file": "e9c4f864-3555-3e8c-b0f7-73f9d4d74348-150x150.jpg",
            "width": 150,
            "height": 150,
            "mime-type": "image/jpeg",
            "source_url": "http://lesexpertes.test/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/e9c4f864-3555-3e8c-b0f7-73f9d4d74348-150x150.jpg"
          }
        },
        "image_meta": {
          "aperture": "0",
          "credit": "",
          "camera": "",
          "caption": "",
          "created_timestamp": "0",
          "copyright": "",
          "focal_length": "0",
          "iso": "0",
          "shutter_speed": "0",
          "title": "",
          "orientation": "0",
          "keywords": [

          ]
        }
      },
      "post": 120,
      "source_url": "http://lesexpertes.test/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/e9c4f864-3555-3e8c-b0f7-73f9d4d74348.jpg"
    },
    "acf": {
      "nom": "Watson",
      "prenom": "Julia",
      "telephone": "022 733 40 31",
      "courriel": "julia@banquise.ch",
      "formation": "<p>Université de Genève &#8211; Master en Ecologie</p>\n"
    },
    "cats": [
      {
        "term_id": 11,
        "name": "Ecologie",
        "slug": "ecologie",
        "term_group": 0,
        "term_taxonomy_id": 11,
        "taxonomy": "category",
        "description": "",
        "parent": 0,
        "count": 23,
        "filter": "raw",
        "cat_ID": 11,
        "category_count": 23,
        "category_description": "",
        "cat_name": "Ecologie",
        "category_nicename": "ecologie",
        "category_parent": 0
      },
      {
        "term_id": 10,
        "name": "Technologies",
        "slug": "technologies",
        "term_group": 0,
        "term_taxonomy_id": 10,
        "taxonomy": "category",
        "description": "",
        "parent": 0,
        "count": 26,
        "filter": "raw",
        "cat_ID": 10,
        "category_count": 26,
        "category_description": "",
        "cat_name": "Technologies",
        "category_nicename": "technologies",
        "category_parent": 0
      }
    ],
    "_links": {
      "self": [
        {
          "href": "http://lesexpertes.test/wp-json/wp/v2/experte/120"
        }
      ],
      "collection": [
        {
          "href": "http://lesexpertes.test/wp-json/wp/v2/experte"
        }
      ],
      "about": [
        {
          "href": "http://lesexpertes.test/wp-json/wp/v2/types/experte"
        }
      ],
      "author": [
        {
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://lesexpertes.test/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1"
        }
      ],
      "wp:featuredmedia": [
        {
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://lesexpertes.test/wp-json/wp/v2/media/121"
        }
      ],
      "wp:attachment": [
        {
          "href": "http://lesexpertes.test/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=120"
        }
      ],
      "wp:term": [
        {
          "taxonomy": "category",
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://lesexpertes.test/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?post=120"
        },
        {
          "taxonomy": "langue",
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://lesexpertes.test/wp-json/wp/v2/langue?post=120"
        }
      ],
      "curies": [
        {
          "name": "wp",
          "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
          "templated": true
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 84,
    "date": "2018-03-29T09:33:04",
    "date_gmt": "2018-03-29T07:33:04",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http://lesexpertes.test/experte/qui-et-similique-deleniti-sint-exercitationem/"
    },
    "modified": "2018-03-29T09:33:04",
    "modified_gmt": "2018-03-29T07:33:04",
    "slug": "qui-et-similique-deleniti-sint-exercitationem",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "experte",
    "link": "http://lesexpertes.test/experte/qui-et-similique-deleniti-sint-exercitationem/",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Qui et similique deleniti sint exercitationem"
    },
```

...

And here is my code:

index.vue

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <main role="main">
      <section class="jumbotron text-center">
        <SearchBox v-model="searchTerm" />
        <RadioGroup v-model="selected" />
        <ExpertesList :expertes="expertes" />
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from 'axios'
  import ExpertesList from '@/components/ExpertesList'
  import SearchBox from '@/components/SearchBox'
  // import Pagination from '@components/Pagination'
  import RadioGroup from '@/components/RadioGroup'

  export default {
    components: {
      ExpertesList,
      SearchBox,
      RadioGroup
    },

    asyncData(context) {
      return axios.get('http://lesexpertes.test/wp-json/wp/v2/experte')
        .then(res => {
          return {
            expertes: res.data,
            orig: res.data
          }
        })
        .catch(e => context.error(e))
    },
    data() {
      return {
        searchTerm: '',
        selected: ''
        // expertes: ''
      }
    },
    computed: {
      result() {
        return this.orig
      }
    },
    watch: {
      searchTerm: function () {
        this.filterExpertes()
      },
      selected: function () {
        this.filterExpertes()
      }
    },
    methods: {
      filterExpertes: function () {
        const searchTerm = this.searchTerm.toLowerCase()
        const selected = this.selected
        let result = this.result
        if (searchTerm) {
          result = result.filter(experte => {
            return (
              experte.title.rendered.toLowerCase().search(searchTerm) >= 0
              // ||
              //experte.description.toLowerCase().search(searchTerm) >= 0
            )
          })
        }

        if (selected) {
          // result = result.filter(experte => {
          //   return (
          //     experte.categories.indexOf(selected) >= 0
          //   )
          // })
          result = result.filter(experte => experte.categories.indexOf(selected) >= 0)
        }
        this.expertes = result
        //this.page = 1
      }
    },
    created: function () {
      this.filterExpertes()
    }
  }
</script>
```

RadioGroup.vue

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <!-- <b-form-group label="Catégories:">
      <b-form-checkbox-group id="checkboxes2" name="flavour2" v-model="selected">
        <b-form-checkbox v-for="cat in cats" :value="cat.id">{{cat.name}}</b-form-checkbox>
      </b-form-checkbox-group>
    </b-form-group> -->
    <div v-for="cat in cats">
      <input type="checkbox" :value="cat.id" v-model="selected">
      <label >{{cat.name}}</label>
    </div>

    <hr>
    <div>Selected:
      <strong>{{ selected }}</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from 'axios';
  export default {
    name: 'RadioGroup',
    mounted: function () {
      //console.log( wp.api.collections );
      this.getCats();
    },
    data() {
      return {
        cats: '',
        selected: []
        //
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getCats: function () {
        const vm = this;
        axios.get('http://lesexpertes.test/wp-json/wp/v2/categories')
          .then((res2) => {
            vm.cats = res2.data;
          })
          .catch((res2) => {
            //console.log( `Something went wrong : ${ res }` );
          });
      }
    },
    watch: {
      selected: function (val) {
        this.$emit('input', val)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

ExpertesList.vue

```
    <template>
  <div>

    <ul>
       <li v-for="experte in expertes">
         {{experte.title.rendered}} - {{experte.categories}}
         </li>
    </ul>
    </div>


</template>

<script>
//import Experte from '@/components/Experte'
export default {
  name: 'ExpertesList',
  //components: { Experte },
  props: ['expertes']
}
</script>
```

SearchBox.vue

```
  <template>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="search" class="form-control input-lg" v-model="searchTerm"
      placeholder="Search the title/description" :name="name">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: {
      default: ''
    },
    name: {
      default: ''
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return { searchTerm: this.value }
  },
  watch: {
    value: function(val) {
      this.searchTerm = val
    },
    searchTerm: function(val) {
      this.$emit('input', val)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Any help / hint welcome...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok ! Short version here but same question: how to filter by the search inbox and by the checkbox http://jsfiddle.net/cfab/de7ncvvf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the problem #1 in your fiddle, but here's a solution for the second one:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    searchQuery: '',
    items: [],
    cats: [{
        id: 2672,
        name: "Autre",
        slug: "autre",
        taxonomy: "category",
        checked: false,
      },
      {
        id: 25,
        name: "Culture",
        slug: "culture",
        taxonomy: "category",
        checked: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  computed: {
    checkedIds() {
      return Object.assign({}, ...this.cats
        .filter(el => el.checked)
        .map(el => ({
          [el.id]: true
        })));
    },
    filteredItems() {
      return this.items.filter((item) => {
        return (
          item.title.rendered.indexOf(this.searchQuery) !== -1 &&
          item.categories.filter(el => this.checkedIds[el]).length > 0
        );
      });
    },
  },
  created: function() {
    const that = this
    axios.get('https://lecourrier.ch/wp-json/wp/v2/posts')
      .then(function(response) {
        that.items = response.data
      });
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search" v-model="searchQuery">
  <div v-for="cat in cats">
    <input type="checkbox" :value="cat.id" v-model="cat.checked">
    <label>{{cat.name}} - cat_id: {{cat.id}}</label>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in filteredItems" :key="item.id">{{ item.title.rendered }} - cat_id: {{item.categories}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Besides filtering by a query string, you need to track the selected categories as well. You can do it by using `v-model` directive on the inputs. Then you can create a map of selected id (take a look of `checkedIds`) and filter your items using it.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oniondomes/b9pdwxgv/)

P.S. use arrow function to avoid writing `var that = this`. Arrow functions don't have it's own `this` so it will refer to the component.